# Django, Apache2 and Mod_WSGI serves data slower than a fax miachine

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a very basic Django instance set up on a RPi model 3. Important as this may indeed be the issue.

I'm using Django 3.2, Python 3.7, Mod_WSGI, compiled from source against this version of python and Apache2, installed via the package manager (`apt install apache2`). Being unfamiliar with the back-end side of things in terms of Python and WSGI, I suspect maybe my set up is the issue... but I digress.

Mod_WSGI is set up in daemon mode:

```
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/steve/steve/steve/wsgi.py
WSGIProcessGroup steve
WSGIDaemonProcess steve python-home=/home/pi/steve/env python-path=/home/pi/steve processes=2 threads=15
#WSGIPythonHome /home/pi/steve/env
#WSGIPythonPath /home/pi/steve
LogLevel debug
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
```

Django collects data from a PSQL database, orders it and serves it using `return JsonResponse(JSONDataSorted, safe=False)`

For now all I am serving is this raw JSON. Its only 700 rows in the format:

`[{"T": "Sun Aug 15 21:51:35 2021", "C": 17.0, "RH": 81.5},...]`

Everything works completely as expected but it is PAINFULLY slow. Checking the request timing, 65ms is spent connecting, 59.29 SECONDS spend waiting and 15ms receiving. If I only return a single row, the time decreases to 30s waiting. Running the queries natively in PSQL with `\timing` on, the results are returned in 2 or 3 secs. Running the query from the Django shell similarly produces a fast query. My view for reference:

```
def last_12_hours(request):
    JSONData = []
    time_frame = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=12) #import datetime
    AtmosphericObjects = Atmospheric.objects.filter(time__gt=time_frame).order_by('-time').all()
    for row in AtmosphericObjects:
        JSONData.append({
            "T": (row.pk).strftime("%c"), 
            "C": (float(row.temperature)), 
            "RH": (float(row.humidity))
            })
        JSONDataSorted = sorted(JSONData, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['T'], '%c'))
    return JsonResponse(JSONDataSorted, safe=False)
```

I set my apache logs to debug and checked the errors.log file. Here is the log right after starting the apache service:

```
[Mon Aug 16 10:55:34.945928 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20498:tid 1996366352] mod_wsgi (pid=20498): Exiting process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.243961 2021] [so:warn] [pid 20921:tid 1995743760] AH01574: module alias_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.255553 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(454): AH010033: Watchdog: Running with WatchdogInterval 1000ms
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.255676 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(462): AH02974: Watchdog: found parent providers.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.255706 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02977: Watchdog: found child providers.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.255732 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(516): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_singleton_).
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.255757 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(516): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_default_).
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.257199 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8514): mod_wsgi (pid=20922): Socket for 'steve' is '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.20922.0.1.sock'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.257442 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(8583): mod_wsgi (pid=20922): Listen backlog for socket '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.20922.0.1.sock' is '100'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.259660 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Starting process 'steve' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.260946 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Python home /home/pi/steve/env.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.261248 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Initializing Python.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.264316 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.264433 2021] [mpm_event:info] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] AH00490: Server built: 2021-06-10T10:13:06
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.264482 2021] [core:notice] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.264509 2021] [core:debug] [pid 20922:tid 1995743760] log.c(1571): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.264649 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20925:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(567): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.265684 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20925:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20925): Initializing Python.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.265877 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Starting process 'steve' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.266960 2021] [watchdog:debug] [pid 20926:tid 1995743760] mod_watchdog.c(567): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.267062 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Python home /home/pi/steve/env.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.267307 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Initializing Python.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.267315 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20926:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20926): Initializing Python.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.398687 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.398961 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20925:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20925): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.398961 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20926:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20926): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.399685 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.451905 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Adding '/home/pi/steve' to path.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.454095 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Adding '/home/pi/steve' to path.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.461057 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20926:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20926): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.461627 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20925:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20925): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.462641 2021] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 20926:tid 1981359136] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.463131 2021] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 20925:tid 1981359136] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.464112 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.466929 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1872253984] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 11 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.466994 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1964573728] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 0 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467120 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1956181024] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 1 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467178 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1947788320] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 2 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467201 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1863861280] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 12 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467288 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1855468576] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 13 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467304 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1939395616] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 3 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467312 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1922610208] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 5 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467341 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1847075872] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 14 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467358 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1931002912] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 4 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467371 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1914217504] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 6 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467421 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1905824800] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 7 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467490 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1897432096] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 8 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467538 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1889039392] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 9 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467588 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20923:tid 1880646688] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20923): Started thread 10 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.467645 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20924:tid 1995743760] mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468245 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1964573728] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 0 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468337 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1956181024] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 1 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468400 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1947788320] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 2 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468475 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1939395616] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 3 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468564 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1931002912] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 4 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468647 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1922610208] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 5 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468722 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1914217504] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 6 in daemon process 'steve'.
[Mon Aug 16 12:55:35.468798 2021] [wsgi:debug] [pid 20924:tid 1905824800] src/server/mod_wsgi.c(9145): mod_wsgi (pid=20924): Started thread 7 in daemon process 'steve'.
```

I notice that 'mod_wsgi' is imported a bunch of times. The number of processes spawned seems unreasonable for my application but everything was running just as slow when I omited `threads=2 processes=15`.

Checking the error.log after I request the page I get this line which looks normal:

```
[Mon Aug 16 12:59:55.425775 2021] [wsgi:info] [pid 20923:tid 1872253984] [remote 10.0.0.10:50953] mod_wsgi (pid=20923, process='steve', application=''): Loading Python script file '/home/pi/steve/steve/steve/wsgi.py'.
```

If I check htop during such a request, apache uses 100% of a CPU core for the time it takes the data to show up in the browser.

Could this simply be as a result of the hardware? Where do I begin? Every answer suggests Daemon mode and I'm using that but either embedded or daemon both take ages and in any case, I am not convinced that the issue isn't actually with Django as the Django server also takes a million years:

`[16/Aug/2021 11:08:27] "GET /last_12_hours HTTP/1.1" 200 45124`

Any suggestions?

Comment: As with all performance tuning: First you'll need to figure out what takes so long. You're retrieving data (`.filter`), then you concatenate your results (`.append`), and then you `sort` the result. Depending on your findings, you'll know what to work on next.

Comment: I've used the debug_toolbar to check under the hood and while the query take 11 seconds to execute, the remaining 50 seems to be all python CPU stuff... I also suspected this particular section, where I am doing a bunch of fiddling with the data from the db to neaten it up a bit. 
To test I made the query results a lot simpler, removed all rows in the DB except one and the results are still very poor. 

Django-debug-toolar tells me that most of the time is taken up by the request and I am starting to think its a Django problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Solution:

The reason for Django taking so long is largely due to the `sorted` function.

I implemented this because my results from the query:

```
AtmosphericObjects = Atmospheric.objects.filter(time__gt=time_frame).order_by('-time').all()
```

were coming in out of order despite the `.order_by('-time')`, which itself is very simply solved by removing `.all()`

So the issue boils down to:

1. Sorting function taking FOREVER to run on a Pi.
2. Me not properly understanding the Django models and querySets.
3. Unnecessarily doing the same thing twice (sorting by time).